# How to initiate an method from another component in blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

So what i have is an ticket handling system im writing in blazor server. So im listing out all the tickets plus some statistics on the front page, and then i have a button on the front page which opens a modal where i can edit and create new tickets.

So what i want to do is, that after i have created a ticket or updated a ticket, i want to immediatly run my method that is on the front page that will load all the data again. So when you exit the modal the new values will be there. At the moment i have to refresh the page to be able to see the new values.

How can i achieve this? I cant use @ref on a child component etc because this modal component is in the mainLayout file and not the specific page file, where the method is.

What ive tried:

- using @ref on child component
- classic .net with "Page page = new Page()" and then "page.LoadData()", syntex wise it works but it gives me a
  nullreferenceobject when calling the method.

So any tips on how to achieve this? or any tips on how i could do this any other way?  i dont want to refresh the page to see the changes.

Thanks

Comment: If your Modal saves changes to the backend, then the backend should trigger an update, not the UI components among each other.

Comment: @Fildor hmm okay, you got any good links on how to achieve that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly

Comment: @philipcode - see a short article here - https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/Notification-Service-Pattern.html - that explains a simple Data Notification Service with some sample code and a working example.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is pass an Action as a parameter to your modal.

Something like:

**MainPage.razor**

```
<Modal OnSubmit="@HandleTicket" />
```

**Modal.razor.cs**

```
public partial class Modal
{
[Parameter]
Action<Ticket> OnSubmit {get;set;}

private Ticket ticket;

private void Submit() // Gets called when you close the modal
{
OnSubmit?.Invoke(ticket);
}
```